# Question On Validate Function On Byte Integer in C#

Tags: c#, integer, c#-2.0, byte, validation

How can I validate a value is `xx` **byte integer** (singed or unsigned)
xx stand for `1`, `2`, `4`, `8`.

Supposed that I need validate `65`(65 was a string value currently) is 1 byte integer or not?

How can I write a tiny function to validate it?

I don't know the exact meaning for *byte integer*.

Comment: Eventually, I found the useful link. http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bool Is1Byte(string val)
{
    try
    {
       int num = int.Parse(val)
       return (num >= -128) && (num <= 127);
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi pivotnig, I can understand the main statement on you input. But what's the meaning for int 128 and 127? Thank you.

Comment: stolen from jackson: A 1 byte integer can contain a number between 0 and 255 (if unsigned) or -128 and 127 if signed

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you need is something that will test a number to see if it fits within a 1 byte integer. A 1 byte integer can contain a number between 0 and 255 (if unsigned) or -128 and 127 if signed. So you just need something that tests to see if the number falls within this range. byte is unsigned by default in C# so you just need:

```
return (x >= 0 && x <= 255);
```

Why these values? It's because a byte is eight bits of storage, which can store 2 to the 8 possible values. 2^8 = 256.

Comment: i think you want to substitute 0 with value, otherwise its always true

Comment: @pivoting: yeah I spotted that as soon as I posted it *shakes*